# find which function(file) causes server overload

Tags: php, debugging, overloading, cpu-usage

I have read [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464327/detect-which-script-causes-server-overload-apache-php), but my topic is not duplicate.

It will be excellent, if I had an specific helper function/method, which will track all further functions, which are being executed in PHP, to determine the each function's execution time, like this:

```
executed URL: /mypage.php
function execution times:
        initialize(): 1.2 seconds
         - cookie_checker(): 0.1 ms
           -- set_cookie():  0.01 ms 
           -- blabla():  0.5 ms
         - start_authorization(): 0.27 ms
        page_output(): 2.4 seconds
         - header_output(): 0.3 ms
           -- XXXXXXXXXXXXX():  0.01 ms 
           -- YYYYYYYYYYYYY():  0.5 ms
         - ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ(): 0.27 ms
```

so, i will have logs and find out which function causes server/CPU overload. Have you any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/phacility/xhprof

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov thanks, i will try this. convert your comment in answer and i will choose it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a free tool for profiling php code you can use XHProf. See https://github.com/phacility/xhprof.

Comment: Also, please include some HO-TO use basics, how can i achieve what i described. p.s. if there is any Commercial tool, tell me that too.